# Clean a filler machine used to dispense epoxy resin

Tags: solutions

I am dispensing epoxy resin and at times epoxy hardener through a filler machine.  It needs to be cleaned after each run, but rather than do a complete tear down, I'd rather be able to complete a "soft clean" between like materials.  For example, doing a soft clean between two runs of different colors.  By "soft clean", I mean running a cleaner through the machine on a cycle mode where the cleaner is run through a 100+ cycles to essentially remove any standing material within any lines and pipe work on the machine.

I'd also prefer to use something to clean with that is not prone to fires or explosion.  I use things like acetone on tools and such but that can be pretty volatile.  I have soaked things in benzyl alcohol before, but that type of alcohol tends to soften/swell things like rubber o rings and such and I need to avoid that.

Does anyone have a cleaning fluid in mind that may work for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might try a paint stripper, such as [Klean-Strip](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klean-Strip-1-Gal-Premium-Paint-Remover-and-Stripper-GKPS300/307994460). However, you'd need to determin a few things in *your particular appliction*.

- Is it effective in removing *thin* layers of adhered epoxy (likely, yes)?
- Is it effective in removing *blobs* of cured epoxy (likely, *quite* slowly).?
- Does it damage seals and gaskets, or even metal parts?

As for flammability, less-flammable alternatives, such as chlorinated or otherwise substituted solvents, tend to be much more toxic and create difficulty when disposing of wastes. Personally, I can deal with care to avoid ignition more easily than working with toxic chemicals.